# $T$ is a linear operator on $V$ and fix $v∈ V$...

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

$T$ is a linear operator on $V$ and fix $v∈ V$. If there is $m∈\Bbb{N}$ such that $T^{m-1}(v)≠ 0$ but $T^{m}(v)=0$, show that ${\{v,Tv,...,T^{m-1}(v)}\}$ is linearly independent.

- I am literally in the dark with this problem, any help is very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a linear combination
$$\alpha_1 v+\alpha_2 Tv+\cdots+\alpha_m T^{m-1}v=0$$
Apply $T^{m-1}$. We get $\alpha_1 T^{m-1}v=0$, but $T^{m-1}v=0\neq 0$; therefore, $\alpha_1=0$.

Do you have an idea how to continue?